# How to fix this non working regex pattern matching?

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7, match

I have a pattern I am trying to match using `re.compile`. However, I cannot get the script to yield the desired result. Below is an example of some HTML code I am hoping to scrape, from the below HTML I hope to produce two list items.

Also below is my attempt at selecting the two list items:

```
import re

def getData():  

    trans_array = "" ##HTML data here
    pattern2 = re.compile('<table width="100%" border="0" class="tbl t3 mobile-collapse">(.*)</table>')

    print re.findall(pattern2, trans_array)

getData()
```

My feeling is that the code I used should work, but it has not. Any advice or comments would be appreciated.

Comment: You should be using the S modifier `re.S` to match newlines with dots `.`. Also don't forget to make your expression ungreedy `(.*?)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default `.` in regular expression does not match new line characters. Add `flags=re.S` parameter to `re.compile`, and your regexp will work.

Answer (score 1):

Unless you tell it otherwise, the `.` in Regex will not match newlines.  However, instead of using `flags=re.S` to fix this, I think a cleaner solution would be to just use the Regex syntax itself:

```
re.compile('(?s)<table width="100%" border="0" class="tbl t3 mobile-collapse">(.*?)</table>')
```

`(?s)` does the same thing as `flags=re.S`.

Also, I think you want to make your matches nongreedy to maximize matching.  That is done by using `(.*?)` instead of `(.*)`